# Flutter in_app_purchase: ^3.1.4 issue on release production

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

hello i am using in_app_purchase: ^3.1.4 official flutter plugin  for purchasing item in my app its non_consumable product user can buy it only one time. i have test this app on internal testing.On internal testing it was working fine but issue was its not working production release anyone know what issue here is my code below please check now

```
  final Set<String> _productIds = {'urdubible'};
  late List<ProductDetails> _products;
  bool _isPurchased = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkPurchaseStatus();
    // initialize the in-app purchase plugin
    InAppPurchase .instance.purchaseStream
        .listen((List<PurchaseDetails> purchases) {
      // handle any purchase updates
      _handlePurchaseUpdates(purchases);
    });

    // load the available products
    _loadProducts();
  }

  Future<void> _loadProducts() async {
    // get the product details from the store
    ProductDetailsResponse response =
    await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(_productIds);
    // save the product details to state
    setState(() {
      _products = response.productDetails;
    });
  }

  void _handlePurchaseUpdates(List<PurchaseDetails> purchases) {
    for (PurchaseDetails purchase in purchases) {
      switch (purchase.status) {
        case PurchaseStatus.purchased:
          _savePurchaseStatus(true);

          // handle the purchase, e.g. update UI, save the purchase to database, etc.
          setState(() {
            _isPurchased = true;

          });
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.error:
        // handle any purchase errors
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.canceled:
        // handle cancelled purchases
          break;
      }
    }
  }


  Future<void> _purchaseProduct() async {
    if (_products.isNotEmpty) {
      // initiate the purchase flow
      final PurchaseParam purchaseParam =
      PurchaseParam(productDetails: _products.first);
      InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
    }
  }


  Future<void> _savePurchaseStatus(bool isPurchased) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('isPurchased', isPurchased);
  }

  Future<void> _checkPurchaseStatus() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool? isPurchased = prefs.getBool('isPurchased');

    if (isPurchased != null && isPurchased) {
      setState(() {
        _isPurchased = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I am facing issue with

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        useProguard false 
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

After disabling shrink resources it's working for me

Comment: i also need add any license key?

Comment: in case you facing any other issues share those error logs so others can also help.

Comment: javdav do i need add  licensing key Base64-encoded RSA public key  which is under monitization setup key?

Comment: @– MohitJadav86 After adding this i am getting this error  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/joshua/Documents/urdubible/android/app/build.gradle' line: 58

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.